# Marking overlapping events per resource (FullCalendar 5, Laravel 7)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, fullcalendar

Using `resourceTimelineWeek` of FullCalendar 5,  I need to check for overlapping events -- not in general but per resource. The goal is to make a red border around the events when they overlap for one resource. I just can't a grip on how to implement this in Laravel 7 using Eloquent. I am getting my events for all resources I want to apply the check on with

```
      protected $appends = ['color','borderColor'];

      $events = Toolplan::query()
        ->select('id', 'eventId', 'resourceId', 'title', 'start', 'end')
        ->where(function ($query) use ($start, $end) {
            $query
                ->where(function ($q) use ($start, $end) {
                    $q->whereDate('start', '>=', $start)->whereDate('end', '<=', $end);
               })
                ->orWhere(function ($q) use ($start, $end) {
                    $q->whereDate('start', '<=', $start)->whereDate('end', '>=', $end);
               })
                ->orWhere(function ($q) use ($start, $end) {
                    $q->whereDate('end', '>=', $start)->whereDate('end', '<=', $end);
               })
                ->orWhere(function ($q) use ($start, $end) {
                    $q->whereDate('start', '>=', $start)->whereDate('start', '<=', $end);
               });
        })
        ->whereIn('eventId', $processIds)
        ->get(); 
        return json_encode($events);
```

in my `Toolplan.php` and would like to work with a Mutator I have also defined in my `Toolplan.php`:

```
    public function getBorderColorAttribute($value)
    {
      $overlaps = $this->eventOverlaps();
      if($overlaps)
        return 'Red';
      return $this->color;
    }
```

The issue is now that I need to determine if two events overlap for one resource and that's where I'm stuck:

```
    public function eventOverlaps()
    {
        (...) // ???
          return true;
        
      return false;
    }
```

I am grateful for any hint in the right direction.

Comment: I guess you need to look for all events where a) the resource IDs match, and b) the end date of one event is between the start and end another event or c) the start date of one event is between the start and end of another event. This is a variant of the overlapping dates problem which is quite common (as it's required for reservation / booking systems etc). How you actually implement using Eloquent I don' know (I'm not familiar with it), but that's the general logic. You can probably find raw SQL implementations available quite easily though.

Comment: Yeah, I am already using the overlapping dates query for getting my events, that's not the issue and I know I need to check events resource Id per resource Id. The problem is that I can't figure out where to put this in Laravel and how to code this exactly. Do I need another query for that or using foreach or are there other methods to get this result?

Comment: That query you showed doesn't look like it does anything with overlapping. But anyway, I guess you need to run your query when you're generating your event data to send to fullCalendar. Beyond that, without more context, i can't suggest anything.

Comment: No problem. The query above is a minimal example where I stripped the orWhere clauses.